# mysql get entry with max count of aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an email_patterns table and I would like to find the most common pattern for each domain:

```
email_patterns
id, domain, pattern
1, microsoft.com, first.last
2, microsoft.com, first.last
3, microsoft.com, last.first
4, microsoft.com, first
5, apple.com, last
6, apple.com, last.first
7, apple.com, last.first
```

The query should return

```
domain, pattern, count
microsoft.com, first.last, 2
apple.com, last.first, 2
```

This is how to get the counts for each domain, pattern combination:

```
SELECT domain, pattern, COUNT(1) count FROM email_patterns GROUP BY domain, pattern;
```

However, I only want to get the domain pattern combination with the highest count for each domain.

Answer (score 1):

Next you just need `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT domain, pattern, cnt
FROM (SELECT domain, pattern, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY domain ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM email_patterns
      GROUP BY domain, pattern
     ) dp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```